# macro para eliminar filas duplicadas

Tags: excel, vba

quiero hacer una macro para eliminar filas duplicadas por ID. El rango no debe seleccionar filas fijas, ya que el fichero se va alimentando con nuevas filas. las columnas siempre permanecen las mismas y en el mismo orden. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias!

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar las filas duplicadas en documentos de Excel puedes hacer uso de una Macro, en tu ventana de Visual Basic vas a agregar el siguiente código:

```
Sub nombremacro()
Dim fila As Long
  With Application
         For fila = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
          If .WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(«A:A»), _
              Cells(fila, 1)) > 1 Then Cells(fila, 1).EntireRow.Delete
      Next fila
       End With
End Sub
```

Después de guardar tu Macro ya las próximas veces que quieras ejecutarla debes hacerlo desde Herramientas/Macro y seleccionar la Macro según el nombre que le asignaste, en el ejemplo le asigne el nombre de `nombremacro`

Comment: Seguramente tu intención de ayudar es buena, pero siguiendo las normas de SOes el OP debe mostrar que ha intentado desarrollar el problema, la respuesta a su pregunta fácilmente puede encontrarlo en Google

Comment: Muchas gracias, John! simplemente tuve que sustituir 1 por 31 y A:A por AE:AE, ya que es donde se encuentran mis IDs.